# why does os.Getenv("SERVER_SOFTWARE") returns blank string for me?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I recently upgraded to the latest version of the Go SDK (1.8.0), and now when I call os.Getenv("SERVER_SOFTWARE") I get a blank string.  I am using this to determine if I am on my local development server or the live environment, and I am not aware of any other way to check.  So an answer to either question would suite me just fine: 1) Why is that returning a blank string now? or 2) Is there some other way to check if I'm on the dev server?

Comment: Does the local development server and the live environment both return a blank string?

Comment: Yes, here are ALL of the environment variables I have on the live site: "TZ=UTC";"PWD=/base/data/home/apps/s~[MY_APP_ID]/[MY_APP_VERSION]";   See my comments on peterSO's answer for my dev site variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I've been finding lots of "hey, I'm dumb and there's a better way" answers to my questions lately.  This seems to be one of those.  So if I back up a step, and address the real question that I'm trying to answer, everything becomes much simpler.  I'm just trying to have a way to determine if I'm on the dev server or the live server.  I was researching a totally unrelated problem, and found this: appengine.IsDevAppServer().  It's fully documented: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#IsDevAppServer, I just never saw it until now.